# bulk convert .mdf and .ldf files from a folder to .bak

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have a folder with more than 300 .mdf and .ldf microsof SQL server database files(recovered from a ransomware attack to our ESXI server then I have no access to SQL server Master db)

Without access to SQL server system databases to fetch database names and ..., How can I bulk convert all these database files to SQL server backup (.bak) files with no need to manually attach them one by one to sql server in SQL management studio.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to convert the MDF/LDF to a BAK file, so you are going to need to reattach the databases.

The database name is usually in the file name; do you know the structure of these databases - did they have more than one data/log file for example?

You could use Powershell to generate a list of discrete names using:

- Get-ChildItem
- Select-Object -unique

And then iterate through that list and use Invoke-SQLCMD to run the CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH commands using:

- foreach
- Where-Object {$listOfFiles -like "$currentItem*.mdf/ldf"}
- Invoke-SQLCMD
- [MSSQLTips Article on Attach/Detach with T-SQL examples](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6222/sql-server-attach-and-detach-database-examples/)